# Set ubuntu locale

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, format, date-time, locale

How can I set my locale and date format to be y/m/d in Arabic?

Machine Info: Ubuntu  9.10

Answer (score 2):

`dpkg-reconfigure locales`